bundler: failed to load command: rake (/opt/jruby/bin/rake) while running in Docker
FROM jruby:9.3
RUN bundle config --global frozen 1
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY .bundle/config /usr/local/bundle/
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install
RUN rm /usr/local/bundle/config
COPY . .
CMD ["./run.sh"]
-----------------------------------------------------
run,sh file
bundle exec rake ci
---------------------
Rakefile
Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:ci) do |t|
  t.cucumber_opts = "--format junit --out reports --format html --out reports/report.html"
end

I get below error when bundle exec rake ci is executed.
bundler: failed to load command: rake (/opt/jruby/bin/rake)
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find jsonpath-1.0.5, faraday-1.0.1, nokogiri-1.10.10-java, multi_json-1.15.0 ...etc
However , RUN bundle install command in Dockerfile install all the gems successfully
This was running fine earlier, but recently started throwing the error, please could someone help here?
